# Distribute executable module

Tags: python, module, distribution, packaging

I developed a program consisting of a package which is executable (i.e. two files `x/__init__.py` and `x/__main__.py`), so I can execute it using  `python -m x`, if the package resides in the python path.

I never tried to distribute Python packages/modules and I don't have any experience in that field (yet)... I already noticed that there are many different systems and now I have three questions:

1. Which system is appropiate for a Python 3(.2) program? distribute? distutils? setuptools?
2. How can I add kind of a "wrapper script" to the distribution that executes the module directly without the hassle with `python -m …` so that the user can just type x (of course the actual name is a bit more unique :) on the shell.
3. How can I do 2. in a platfom-independent way?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use either `distribute` or `setuptools`, the former is a fork of the latter, with some improvements and better documentation. Either one is a big step up from `distutils`, which is part of the python standard library.
2. You want a console script, for which you define an entry point:

   ```
   entry_points = {
       'console_scripts': [
           'foo = my_package.some_module:main_func',
           'bar = other_module:some_func',
       ],
   ```

   where `foo` and `bar` would be scripts that you can call on the command line. The indicated function will be called with `sys.argv[1:]` as the first and only argument.
3. Let the installation tools take care of that; it works fine on Windows. :-)