# setup.py: restrict the allowable version of the python interpreter

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, setup.py

I have a Python library. Unfortunately I have not updated it to work with Python 3 yet.

In its `setup.py`, I added

```
install_requires=['python<3'],
```

My intent was to not allow this package to be installed/used under Python 3, because I know it doesn't (yet) work. I don't think this is the right way to do it, because `pip` then tries to download and install python 2.7.3 (which is already the installed version!).

How should I specify my library dependency on a particular range of Python interpreter versions? Should I add a `Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only` tag? Will this actually prevent installation under Python 3? What if I also want to restrict the minimum version to Python 2.6?

I'd prefer a solution that works everywhere, but would settle for one that only works in `pip` (and hopefully doesn't cause `easy_install` to choke).

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385337/distribute-distutils-specify-python-version

Comment: Relevant: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#classifiers, which mentions that "Although the list of classifiers is often used to declare what Python versions a project supports, this information is only used for searching & browsing projects on PyPI, not for installing projects. To actually restrict what Python versions a project can be installed on, use the python_requires argument."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of [version 9.0.1](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) pip will honor a new `python_requires` string, specifying the Python version required for installation, e.g, for example if one wishes to enforce minimum Python version of 3.3:

```
setup(
    ...,
    python_requires=">=3.3"
)
```

See [here](http://www.python3statement.org/practicalities/) for more details. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42792413/28035) on SO.

Comment: I think it is worth editing the answer to include the fact that the project MUST be installed using `pip3 install [-e]` as it mentioned in the first link you provided.

Comment: @GuyAvraham Could you clarify your comment? `pip2 install` should honor this as well if it's a recent enough version of pip (as far as I can tell, pip 9.0 is compatible back to python 2.6).

Comment: I added an answer to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 19):

A possible solution is to *test* for the Python version, since `pip` can't *satisfy* the Python version except for the version it's currently running in (it installs in the current Python environment):

```
import sys
if not sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    sys.exit("Sorry, Python 3 is not supported (yet)")

setup(...
```

Comment: True, that would work. It'd be much nicer to have something built into the dependencies though, so that pip would know up-front not to bother downloading and running the installer.

Comment: Why not both? Your answer is what one should *not* do but rather rely on the builtin features, although using this answer *additionally* to the `python_requires` would be great! You may update that?

Answer (score 4):

After commenting in the answer above and receiving feedback, I thought to turn my comment into an answer. Note that the answers above are all fine, yet from my experience, I found one thing that is "missing" in these answers, that needs to be pointed out, so here I will illustrate this issue.

For simplicity and completeness of illustration, I have composed a very minimal and simple Python 3 project. The only 3rd party package it uses, is the famous SSH client package `paramiko` (it's official PyPi page can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/)).

The Python interpreter in the virtual environment of my project is of version **3.6.9**

Now, in order to check the `python_requires` attribute "in action", I have added it to the project's `setup.py` script, which looks as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mySampleProject',
      version='1.0',
      description='Sample project in Python 3',
      author='Guy Avraham',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      python_requires='>=3.8',
      install_requires=['paramiko'])
```

Note that I "required" that the Python version will be **3.8+**. This of course should **NOT** work with the current Python version in the project's virtual environment which is 3.6.9.

Now, when I build the project using the "normal" use in the `setup.py`, meaning by running: `python3 setup.py install`, the project was built successfully. See the following output of the `pip3 list` command after running the `python3 setup.py install` command:

```
(mySampleProject_env) guya@ubuntu:~/mySampleProject$ pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use -- 
format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
bcrypt (3.2.0)
cffi (1.14.3)
cryptography (3.1.1)
mySampleProject (1.0)
paramiko (2.7.2)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
pycparser (2.20)
PyNaCl (1.4.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.15.0)
```

As you can see, the project, along with all its "sub dependencies" was installed EVEN though I was NOT expecting it to.

**On the other hand**, when I installed the project using the command: `pip3 install -e .` (note the `.` to indicate the "current working directory"), I got the following output:

```
(mySampleProject_env) guya@ubuntu:~/mySampleProject$ pip3 install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/guya/mySampleProject
mySampleProject requires Python '>=3.8' but the running Python is 3.6.9
```

Which now, indeed, "considers" the `python_requires` attribute, thus "failing" the build of the project.

It is detailed in the very first paragraph in the tutorial in [this page](https://python3statement.org/practicalities/)
and also during minutes ~09:00 - 11:00 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DkfPzWWC2Q)

**NOTE:** I did **NOT** check all the above for Python 2 (or `pip` for Python 2).

Comment: I think this is because you have an old version of setuptools with your python 3.6.9. If you `pip install -U setuptools` I'm guessing it will honor the `python_requires` argument. Awkward that this functionality is relatively recent, because it's most needed with the old versions of python!

Comment: @Noah - I tried what you have suggested: Created virtual environment using `venv` with Python 3.8.5 (Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop). The `setuptools` version was 44.0.0. Upgraded the `setuptools` as you suggested to version 50.3.2, performed installation using the "normal setup.py install" (i.e. - `python3 setup.py install`), yet the `python_requires` "attribute" was still not taking into consideration (i.e. - the project was installed successfully, even though the Python version is 3.8.5 and I asked for >=3.9). When I did it with the command `pip3 install -e .`, the installation failed (as required).