# What's the proper way for a Python project to declare it requires Python 3 vs Python2?

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, requirements.txt

*Disclaimer:* I'm not a Python programmer, just someone who needs to deal with / inspect (dependencies of) Python projects.

Given a Python project, usually declared by either a `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` file ([or both](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/)), what is the machine-readable way to say that "this project requires Python 3" or "this project requires Python2", if there is such a way?

I've been reading e.g. through [Core metadata specifications](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/), but this seems to refer to `PKG-INFO` files that are part of source distributions (`sdist`). However, what I'm looking for is information for a user or contributor to an Open Source project which, given only the source code of a Python project as checked out from a VCS, instructs whether to use Python 3 or Python 2 for that project. Human-readable hints in a `README.md` is not what I'm after, but some well-defined / standardized meta-data in a machine readable format.

Background: I'm looking at fully automatically determining all dependencies of a Python project, and in order to do so, I also need to know which version of Python is required.

**Edit:** Following the link in @mkrieger1's comment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777286/1127485) suggests that at least in case of `setup.py` the answer is to use a `python_requires` directive. However, the question is still open for pure `requirements.txt` projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforcing python version in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534896/enforcing-python-version-in-setup-py)