# How to define "python_requires" in pyproject.toml using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

Setuptools allows you to specify the minimum python version [as such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777286/2135504):

```py
from setuptools import setup

[...]

setup(name="my_package_name",
      python_requires='>3.5.2',
      [...]
```

However, how can you do this with the [pyproject.toml](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html)? The following two things did NOT work:

```
[project]
...
# ERROR: invalid key 
python_requires = ">=3"

# ERROR: no matching distribution found
dependencies = ["python>=3"]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/), the equivalent field in the `[project]` table is [`requires-python`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#requires-python).

More information about the list of valid configuration fields can be found in: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/.

The equivalent `pyproject.toml` of your example would be:

```ini
[project]
name = "my_package_name"
requires-python = ">3.5.2"
...
```

Comment: This is documented https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python but I didn't believe it wouldn't parse `requires-python = "3.10"` but checking with Ruff https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/ confirmed it wouldn't, and it doesn't like `"=3.10"` either, but `"~=3.10"` passes.

Comment: @NeilG I believe equality should be specified as `==3.10`. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#version-matching

Comment: Thanks @JonathanHartley :facepalm: - that's why that didn't work then I guess.

Answer (score 4):

To force the use of an *exact* micro-version of CPython, use the syntax:

`requires-python = ">=3.11.1,<3.11.2"`