# Is it possible to restrict the Python version in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Is it possible to restrict the availability of a python package to a certain Python runtime, e.g. Python>=2.7,<3

I feel like the solutions already posted elsewhere on here ([setup.py: restrict the allowable version of the python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924931/setup-py-restrict-the-allowable-version-of-the-python-interpreter) and [Enforcing python version in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534896/enforcing-python-version-in-setup-py)) aren't ideal because they perform a runtime version check in the `setup.py` file.

Isn't it possible that a package's metadata needs to be read on one computer, to determine the package's availability for another computer?

For instance, suppose a package repository wants to index the metadata for a collection of packages. It does so using Python 3, but for this particular package, the `setup.py` script throws an exception. A Python 2.7 client then connects to the index and can't find the package in question, because it failed to be indexed by the Python 3-based indexer.

Comment: I think the fact that the answers there say "do the explicit check" mean the answer is: no there is no way directly supported by setuptools.