# Allow a requirements.txt to be executed only from python3 context

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

While installing from requirements.txt, as under:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I want to restrict to a context of Python3 only. If attempted from Python2 context, it should throw an error.

How can I accomplish the above?

Comment: I don't think this is possible from the `requirements.txt`.  You may want to look into using a `setup.py` file.  [From there you can specify a `python_requires` string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924931/setup-py-restrict-the-allowable-version-of-the-python-interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

Turn your project into [a proper package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/), and make use of the `python_requires` string.  If you want to be absolutely sure (i.e. ensure older versions of `pip` will also not run under Python 2), in the `setup.py` include something like this before the `setup` call

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    raise RuntimeError('unsupported python version')

setup(...
```

Naturally, declare all the dependencies in the `setup.py` so that other packages that depend on this one will get them without having to rely on a separate file.

If you still want to make use of `requirements.txt`, also add this to the following:

```
-e .
```

Which will trigger your package to be installed, thus `setup.py` should be invoked and then the exception will be raised which should abort the installation.

Comment: "Also add this to the following" is a little unclear.  Maybe just put the whole thing there?