# When/where should I check for the minimum Python version?

Tags: python, pip, compatibility

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script) tells me **how** to check the version of Python. For my package I require at least Python 3.3:

```
MIN_VERSION_INFO = 3, 3

import sys
if not sys.version_info >= MIN_VERSION_INFO:
    exit("Python {}.{}+ is required.".format(*MIN_VERSION_INFO))
```

but **where/when** should this check occur?

I want to produce the clearest possible error message for users installing via `pip` (sdist and wheel) or `python setup.py install`. Something like:

```
$ pip -V
pip x.x.x from ... (Python 3.2)
$ pip install MyPackage
Python 3.3+ is required.

$ python -V
Python 3.2
$ python setup.py install
Python 3.3+ is required.
```

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385337/distribute-distutils-specify-python-version

Comment: @sharth the accepted answer on that question says to put it in `setup.py`. Will that work with all methods of distribution including wheels?

Comment: Or would `__init__.py` be better?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the others ask and answer how, not where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary point of a compatibility check is to have this check either elegantly handle a compatibility issue or gracefully exit with an explanation before the incompatibility causes problems.

I'd put it near the top of `setup.py`, or the first script that belongs to you that will be called. Best practice is not to include code in `__init__.py` (unless you're making a MAJOR package, I'd opine), but if you already have a lot of code there, it's fine.

The quickest point of reference I can find: The old [Python 2.6 `unittest` module had a test for it near the top](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Lib/unittest.py#l70), naturally, after the module docstring, imports, and `__all__`.

[Another point of reference shows a compatibility check in an `__init__.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Lib/bsddb/__init__.py#l43), again, near the top, though here it is immediately after the docstring and an import of `sys`, required for the check. There are other similar examples of this usage in `__init__.py` in this same set of libraries.

Comment: What about wheels? I'm pretty sure `setup.py` is not part of the wheel distribution.

Comment: If you think `__init__.py` is appropriate for your package, go for it. I'm adding to the body a bit more.

Comment: I'm going to put the check in `__init__.py` to ensure it works for all distribution methods.