# How to determine the minimal python version in setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py

I'd like to reorganize my project as described [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) to be able to work on it with my friends. Unfortunately I don't know any way to determine python version >= 3 as meta data inside the setup block.
I know I could do an if-statement like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385337/distribute-distutils-specify-python-version) but I wonder why I cannot just state in in the setup settings (like with composer in php). I would have thought that the minimal version of the interpreter would be the first requirement to make...
I additionally cannot find a really complete listing of options to use in the setup block.
So is there really no way to determine the python version "the right way"? ;)

Comment: That *is* the right way; see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19534896/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13924931/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe but why? is there any reason to not include this inside the setup block?