# Prevent package from being installed on old Python versions

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

What can we put in a `setup.py` file to prevent pip from collecting and attempting to install a package when using an unsupported Python version?

For example [`magicstack`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/magicstack/) is a project listed with the trove classifier:

```
Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
```

So I expect the following behaviour if `pip --version` is tied to python 2.7:

```
$ pip install magicstack
Collecting magicstack
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement magicstack (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for magicstack
```

But the actual behavior is that pip collects a release, downloads it, attempts to install it, and fails.  There are other Python3-only releases, [`curio`](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio) for example, which actually install fine - because the `setup.py` didn't use anything Python 3 specific - only to fail at import time when some Python 3 only syntax is used.  And I'm sure there are packages which install OK, import OK, and maybe only fail at runtime!

**What is the correct method to specify your supported Python versions in a way that pip will respect?**  I've found a workaround, involving uploading only a wheel file, and refusing to uploading a .tar.gz distribution, but I would be interested to know the correct fix.

---

*Edit:*  How does pip know *not* to download the wheel distribution if the Python/os/architecture is not matching?  Does it just use the [.whl filename convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention) or is there something more sophisticated than that happening behind the scenes?  Can we somehow give the metadata to a source distribution to make pip do the right thing with .tar.gz uploads?

Comment: I don't know that this is the _right_ answer... but if `magicstack` is python3 only because `setup.py` fails on python2.x, then it seems like one possible way to make this work is to force your `setup.py` to fail on inappropriate python versions...

Comment: Hacky.  If pip is tied to unsupported Python interpreter, I don't want the package collected or downloaded at all, let alone an installation attempted by executing `setup.py`.

Comment: Google turns up some [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924931/setup-py-restrict-the-allowable-version-of-the-python-interpreter) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385337/distribute-distutils-specify-python-version) with answers saying to have your `setup.py` check the Python version.

Comment: Relevant: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#classifiers, which mentions that "Although the list of classifiers is often used to declare what Python versions a project supports, this information is only used for searching & browsing projects on PyPI, not for installing projects. To actually restrict what Python versions a project can be installed on, use the python_requires argument."

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64386359/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362425/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777286/1959808

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a correct way to do this, but unfortunately pip only started supporting it in version 9.0.0 (released 2016-11-02), and so users with older versions of pip will continue to download packages willy-nilly regardless of what Python version they're for.

In your `setup.py` file, pass `setup()` a `python_requires` argument that lists your package's supported Python versions as a [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) [version specifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers).  For example, if your package is for Python 3+ only, write:

```
setup(
    ...
    python_requires='>=3',
    ...
)
```

If your package is for Python 3.3 and up but you're not willing to commit to Python 4 support yet, write:

```
setup(
    ...
    python_requires='~=3.3',
    ...
)
```

If your package is for Python 2.6, 2.7, and all versions of Python 3 starting with 3.3, write:

```
setup(
    ...
    python_requires='>=2.6, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, <4',
    ...
)
```

And so on.

Once you've done that, you will need to upgrade your version of setuptools to at least 24.2.0 in order for the `python_requires` argument to be processed; earlier versions will just ignore it with a warning.  All of your project's sdists and wheels built afterwards will then contain the relevant metadata that tells PyPI to tell pip what Python versions they're for.

Comment: @wim: What version specifier did you use for `python_requires`?

Comment: I've uploaded a [source distribution](https://pypi.python.org/simple/pynapple) for testing on pypi (see [here](https://github.com/wimglenn/pynapple) for the implementation), and it seems to be working as you've described on pypi.  I could only reproduce incorrect behaviour on a different index.  It's possible I've come across a bug in [devpi server](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/), will investigate more tomorrow...

Comment: See here for a lot more useful information:http://www.python3statement.org/practicalities/

Comment: My problem was indeed due to bug in the index (older versions of devpi server are not serving `python_requires` metadata correctly - I believe it's resolved in current releases though).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the project MUST be installed using `pip3 install [-e]` (and not "straightforward" using `python3 setup.py install`) as mentioned here: https://python3statement.org/practicalities/

Answer (score 1):

The `magicstack` distribution on pypi is broken.  It's failing because the source distribution doesn't contain a `magicstack` package even though the `setup.py` for the source distribution says it should.

As long as pypi contains a source distribution (e.g. `.tar.gz`, `.zip`), pip will download that if it can't find a matching binary distribution (e.g. `.egg`, `.whl`) for your version of python/os/architecture.

One option is to only upload binary distributions to PyPI (preferably `wheels`). The other option is to check the `sys.version` in your `setup.py` for compatible versions and raise an exception otherwise.